# How to generate MapR ticket in Python Code

Tags: python, docker, containers, mapr

I am trying to create MapR ticket for different users on demand. This I am doing manually by running a script which deploys a pod and copying the ticket to secret in Kubernetes. Now, I want to do this from python excluding the dependency of script. Is there any Python API's for MapR to generate ticket.

Currently, I am running a script which deploys a pod in kubernetes providing MapR cluster details as environment variables for the pod. Inside the pod, I am running [mapr-setup.sh](https://package.mapr.com/releases/installer/mapr-setup.sh)  script and executing  `maprlogin password` command to generate ticket for the respective user. Then, I am copying the contents of the ticket file and generating MapR ticket secret.

Now, I want to remove the script which deploys a pod for the generation of ticket. Instead, I want to generate MapR ticket for the user by calling some API endpoints of MapR. Is there any API in MapR which gives me provision to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using `maprlogin password` is the correct way to generate a ticket for most purposes.

Ping me directly at ted.dunning@hpe.com for a more nuanced discussion.